# Interrupt Actor - Custom Cancellation Token coming from parent service

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

A thread is spawned with cancellationTokenSource passed as an argument.

```
RootStatefulService
{
    var cts= new CancellationTokenSource();
    ThreadStart starter = ()=> ParentMethod(Message.Value, cts);

    Thread t = new Thread(starter);
    t.Start();
    ...

    // When there is cancel request from client, below code runs
    cts.Token.Cancel();
}
```

In this ParentMethod,  there is Actor being created and again trying to pass down the CancellationToken.

```
ParentMethod(SomeValue value, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    var actorWithToken = ActorProxy.Create<IActorWithToken>(
                      actorId,
                      new Uri(ActorWithTokenUrl));

    actorWithToken.StartLongRunningTask(someId, cts);

    cts.Token.Register(() => { StopImmediatelyAndTerminateActor});
}
```

It is custom token and upon client request, the RootStatefulService.cts.Cancel() is called. From the stateful service to actor, I am not sure if the Cancellation Token Source reference is delivered so that Token.Cancel() invoke in the root service is propagated down to the actor Token.Register method. I am not being successful.  And if this should not work, please answer the correct way to invoke custom Token.Cancel() to propagate down to the spawned actor.

Comment: Could you re-phrase your question, please?  I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: This question would be specific to those who understand Service Fabric services including Actors.

Comment: It was the (now edited) "Has anybody seen this canceltokensource working?", I was not clear on.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure why are you passing `CancellationTokenSource` rather than `CancellationToken`? Can you clarify in more details what effect you want to achieve in `StartLongRunningTask` method?

Comment: I am asking because if `StartLongRunningTask` method would accept `CancellationToken` then you can create an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` inside `ParentMethod` and pass `CancellationTokenSource.Token` to `actorProxy.StartLongRunningTask(id, token)` method. Now when `CancellationTokeSource.Cancel()` is called the `CancellationToken` passed to `StartLongRunningTask` method will be signaled and it `IsCancellationRequested` property would be set to true.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One thing I found out very recently is that cancellationtokensource was the reason the Token.Register() was not calledback correctly. As I pass argument as the token itself instead of token source, seemingly at least in this single partition architecture, I see .Register() methods being invoked.  I am still trying to figure out exact reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create threads to call actors, the proxy implementation make asynchronous calls to the target actor service, you should make these calls asynchronous instead.

The approach you used has many flaws.

- The `CancellationTokenSource` should be controlled by only one owner, you should only pass their `CancellationToken` to the called methods.
- With this approach, you have to abort the thread via via `Thread.Abort()` but does not send a cancellation request to the actor.
- If the method does not get blocked in the `actorWithToken.StartLongRunningTask(someId, cts);` operation to wait it finishes, the method completes the execution and the thread will be completed.
- When the Cancellation happens outside the thread, the `cts.Token.Register(() => { StopImmediatelyAndTerminateActor});` will call the `StopImmediatelyAndTerminateActor` method in a context that does not exist anymore, and may cause many issues hard to identify

Regarding the code, you should be able to make the call like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

string uri = "fabric:/appName/ActorServiceName";
var actor = ActorProxy.Create<IMyActorInterface>(new ActorId(id), new Uri(uri));
Task<int> actorResut = actor.GetCountAsync(cts.Token);

//here you can manage what you want to do
//You could get the result like
var count = await actorResut;

//you can check if it has completed like this
if(actorResut.IsCompleted) {}

//you can cancel the task calling cancel on CTS
cts.Cancel();
```

There are some caveats with this approach for long running operations:

- Only the caller can cancel the operation, because it locks the call to the caller and it must be alive to cancel a remote operation. In case the cancelation request comes from an API, your requests must always go to the same instance that initiated the operation, and in most cases is not guaranteed to happen when behind a load balancer and you have many instances of it running.
- An actor operation has a timeout, this timeout can cancel the operation before it finishes, you can increase it [via settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-fabrictransportsettings)
- The actor runtime has some retry logic in it, when an operation fail it will retry, you can get duplicate processing requests.

Comment: Are you sure you can't pass CancellationToken as a parameter to actor method?  It seemingly works and unless deprecated, the link also shows it works.  Read "CancellationToken support for IService/IActor" part.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/02/23/service-fabric-sdk-v1-5-175-and-the-adoption-of-virtual-machine-scale-sets/

Comment: You are correct, I have corrected the answer, sorry.

Comment: To accept your answer, 1) Thread.abort, I believe still can be done as cancellation token is passed down to the running thread and multicast delegate (as later delegate) can handle aborting the thread as the cancellation process finishes. 2) Threads still need to used as allow parallel processings on single user. 3) In the current architecture, cancellation token sources are managed by single owner using linked token in stateful service.  4) Third bullet point above, it's gotta be token itself not cts.

Comment: 5) For the fourth bullet point, as described in 2) and 3), you can remove the token and you can check if token exists when requests come in (good point though)  6) For the fifth bullet point, I rely on your answer on the other post that single partition with stateful service should work.  Thanks for your persistent help which helped me a lot in making decisions. Please reflect these two comments applied above to be accepted.